# CsvHelper add `;` after last value/column

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Is there any configuration or something that will let me add `;` after last value?

```
FirstName;SecondName
A;B
```

I need it to be

```
FirstName;SecondName;
A;B;
```

Here's my code:

```
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fd.FileName, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Delimiter = ";",
    });

    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<DataRowClassMap>();
    csv.WriteRecords(_rows);
}
```

Thanks in advance

edit. Map Class

```
public sealed class DataRowClassMap : ClassMap<DataRow>
{
    public DataRowClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ListingNumber).Ignore();
        Map(m => m.FirstName).Index(0).Name("FirstName");
        Map(m => m.LastName).Index(1).Name("LastName");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have an dummy empty property with an empty name? May you share the DataRowClassMap btw. You can specify column index in the map, so it's always the last.

Comment: @DragandDrop haha yea, I just came with it, but it's ugly hack as hell `Func<DataRow, string> func = x => ""; Map(x => x.HackForCommaAfterLastColumn).Index(29).Name("").ConvertUsing(func);`

Comment: the other option may be to not use `WriteRecords` but  a `foreach` + `WriteRecord` without s and a `WriteField` to add the ';'

Comment: @DragandDrop yup, dillema of lazy + hack vs not lazy ;) You meant like that? ``foreach (var item in _rows){csv.WriteRecord(item);csv.WriteField(";");}`` for some reason it produces empty file, hmm...

Comment: Missing a csv.NextReccord() after the write field. and it should work. Brain compiler telling me something is off. But can't figure what without a proper edi.

Comment: Btw instead of writting `";"` we need to write `""` because `;` would be escaped to `";"`. Anyway, thanks, please write it as an answer so I'll accept. My code is in main post

Comment: You should put the answer in the answer box and not in the question it self. Feel free to answer your own question. I don't call dips for those small hint and brainstorming we had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution - loop:

```
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fd.FileName, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Delimiter = ";",
    });

    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<DataRowClassMap>();

    csv.WriteHeader<DataRow>(); // write headers
    csv.WriteField(""); // it will be `;` in file
    csv.NextRecord();

    foreach (var item in _rows)
    {
        csv.WriteRecord(item); // actual data 
        csv.WriteField(""); // it will be `;` in file
        csv.NextRecord();
    }
}
```

Second solution - hack, creating new property:

```
public sealed class DataRowClassMap : ClassMap<DataRow>
{
    public DataRowClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ListingNumber).Ignore();
        Map(m => m.FirstName).Index(0).Name("FirstName");
        Map(m => m.LastName).Index(1).Name("LastName");

        // solution hack
        Func<DataRow, string> func = x => "";
        Map(x => x.HackForCommaAfterLastColumn).Index(3).Name("").ConvertUsing(func);
    }
}
```